# where to download gentoo 2.2?

Tags: gentoo, iso, distributions

My hosting company has gentoo. I want to install the same system on my virtualbox/vagrant.
If I do cat /etc/gentoo-release I get:

```
Gentoo Base System release 2.2
```

and uname -r:

```
2.6.32.53-grsec-x86_64
```

where can I get iso of this system? I need the exact same version.

thanks.

Comment: Gentoo is a rolling release distribution...

Answer (score 2):

Well, all Gentoo releases are 2.2. Since Gentoo is not a distribution that has releases (i.e. in stepped increments), you won't find that around. Gentoo is a rolling release, which means all packages are continuously updated, there's no global system version like Ubuntu or Fedora. In short `/etc/gentoo_release` is irrelevant of the system «version».

What you want probably is a Gentoo distribution with the same kernel sources. Bear in mind that such an old kernel may or may not work with recent system packages such as udev, bluetooth. Expect some recent packages a) require a recent kernel version and b) wouldn't even compile otherwise.

Fact [kernel ebuilds](https://packages.gentoo.org/package/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources) for 2.6.32 no longer are available:

- the oldest versions of [hardened-sources](https://packages.gentoo.org/package/sys-kernel/hardened-sources) are 3.2.68, just like the vanilla kernel;
- the only (publicly available) kernel source tree that includes 2.6.32 if [pf-sources](https://packages.gentoo.org/package/sys-kernel/pf-sources).

You'll have to try.

As per my own experience, I have seen not too many differences between a system that can run a 3.2 kernel and one with 2.6.32 so with a little luck and a good deal of work... Just keep in mind that [glibc should be recompiled against the kernel headers](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-816895-start-0.html), which correspond to the installed kernel source tree.

Comment: Old ebuilds are available from the [Gentoo CVS server](https://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/?hideattic=0), though the older ones may not be compatible with current versions of Portage.

Answer (score 1):

As a Gentoo user, as my regular desktop, I have to say that both the answers here, are only half correct.

```
[I] sys-libs/glibc
     Available versions:  (2.2) 2.13-r4^s 2.14.1-r3^s 2.15-r3^s 2.16.0^s 2.17^s ~2.18-r1^s ~2.19^s 2.19-r1^s ~2.20^s ~2.20-r1^s 2.20-r2^s **2.21^s **9999^s
       {debug gd hardened multilib nscd profile selinux suid systemtap vanilla CROSSCOMPILE_OPTS="headers-only"}
     Installed versions:  2.20-r2(2.2)^s(10:40:38 PM 04/04/2015)(gd multilib -debug -hardened -nscd -profile -selinux -suid -systemtap -vanilla CROSSCOMPILE_OPTS="-headers-only")
     Homepage:            http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html
     Description:         GNU libc6 (also called glibc2) C library
```

If you read the Installed Version, you'll see that version 2.20-r2 of the glibc system library is installed which fills slot 2.2.  This is confirmed by the output of `cat /etc/gentoo-release` which outputs:

> Gentoo Base System release 2.2

as you've noted.

---

### Explanation

The other answers are correct in that Gentoo is a rolling release.  The release number is chosen by the version of `sys-libs/glibc` because every compiled package on the system depends on glibc.  As such, this is how Gentoo chooses the release number. This is also true for every binary distribution like Ubuntu.  All packages chosen by the maintainers, all depend on a chosen version of glibc.  If you look at the [Glibc GNU Software Page](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), you'll read:

> Overview
>
> Any Unix-like operating system needs a C library: the library which
>   defines the "system calls" and other basic facilities such as open,
>   malloc, printf, exit...
>
> The GNU C Library is used as the C library in the GNU systems and most
>   systems with the Linux kernel.
>
> Project Goals
>
> The GNU C Library is primarily designed to be a portable and high
>   performance C library. It follows all relevant standards including ISO
>   C11 and POSIX.1-2008. It is also internationalized and has one of the
>   most complete internationalization interfaces known.

Knowing this, and seeing that Version 2.20 was released on 2014-Sept-7, any release you download from the [Gentoo Downloads](https://www.gentoo.org/downloads/), that's dated past 2014-Sept-7 will result in the proper release to start with.  After downloading this, you must follow the proper [Gentoo Handbook for your architecture](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:Main_Page).  You can use the Hybrid CD, which the other posters referred to as the Live DVD Release, or the minimal CD, which your ISP used to create their own server with the handbook. As other posters have noted, with a rolling release this version number may change as you update the system using portage.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other linux distros, you don't just get a Gentoo iso, hit setup and sit back, having a coffee, while setup does everything. Instead, you grab a `stage` and start *building* and *compiling* you OS.

Luckily, for those who only need to get a feeling of Gentoo, there's a live release from time to time (already compiled and put together).

In your case, you either grab a stage and start *building* around the kernel release you need (2.6.32), or get the oldest live available (dated October 2009) based on kernel 2.6.30 from [here](http://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/amd64/10.1/) (link for `amd64`, but have a look around, you'll find it for other archs also).

Comment: "Instead, you grab a stage and start building and compiling you OS." ... and all other apps that you desire. In the meantime, depending on the software you wish to install, you go on vacation for a week or so. - just kidding, it's not so bad.

Comment: That link for live is dead now, I wanted to test it on my old PC Duron 850MHz and 256MB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't actually want 2.2 since that's fairly meaningless.

If you want the exact same setup, you can migrate and existing setup. https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-534039-start-0.html is a rough guide. So long as the image you want copied isn't using options that your hardware doesn't support.

Other sorts of images can work, that advantage of the above guide is that you can do it from within the install.

Not exactly hassle free, you'll have to ch root in after extraction and do some setup. Not easy, but not too difficult if you've done an install a few times, process is basically the same.

The image of the hosting company may be paravirtualized, but the good news is kernel ABI is stable, so you shouldn't have any issues configuring a newer kernel to run the image.